# Issue with Broadcom 4313 under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10

I have been stucked for almost a week finding way to make my wifi work. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 as the title says

Well I have **Broadcom BCM4313**, right now I've followed all possible steps by
purging bcmwl-kernel-source and blacklisting wl and other stuffs.

I know that there are issue similar like this, anyone who has workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll I resolved this issue by applying the patch from broadcom, after that i rebuild the source using make command. after that I rebooted and it works pretty well.

They said that this issue is existing in broadcom drivers

Answer (score 0):

May I assume you are currently using the driver brcmsmac? Confirm:

```
lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcm -e b43
```

The driver brcmsmac requires firmware. Check the message logs for clues:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e brcm
```

If, as I suspect, the firmware is missing, please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get-update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Unload and reload the driver so it sees and uses the new firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac && sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

If no driver shows as being loaded from *lsmod*, load the driver from the terminal, noting any errors or warnings:

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Does your wireless come to life? If so, we'll look for blacklists and get it to load automatically. If not, check for errors in the message log:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e brcm
```

Comment: This doesn't give me anything `lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcm -e b43` also `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e brcm` any clue:(

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually more than one wireless adapter with the model name 4313.  You'll need the pci id.  Type or copy and paste into terminal:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

You should also install linux-firmware-nonfree.

If (AND ONLY IF) the pci id is 14e4:4727 (rev 01) like the one in my netbook is, see:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191126&page=2&p=12889620#post12889620

... which worked for me.  If it's another one it MAY work but I would certainly not guarantee it.

The worst thing you can do is blindly try everything you find on the web.  There is a lot of good ubuntu advice, also a lot of bad ...

Also, if you ask the question clearly here or at the ubuntu forums with info like above you'll get much better support.  I realize that's not easy for novices but it gets better.  There are some serious experts here (unlike me).